# Show that $(U_{n})_{n \leq N}$ is the smallest $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-super-martingale that dominates $X_{n}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition, martingales

I'm doing an exercise about martingale:

> [image]

Could you please explain what **smallest** and **dominates $X_n$** mean in this context?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(U_n)$ dominates $X_n$ means $X_n \leq U_n$. Smallest means if $(V_n)$ is another super-martingale such that $X_n \leq V_n$ then $U_n \leq V_n$.